# python hdfs remote upload file to hdfs

Tags: python, hadoop, hdfs

I want to remote upload file to my hdfs by python module "hdfs".
My hadoop is run in my linux， but I want to remote upload file which in my windows(or other computer). When I use code like:

```
from hdfs import InsecureClient
client = InsecureClient('http://xx.xx.xx.xx:50070', user='user')
```

I can use `client.walk('/')` to view the dirs, but I can't upload file, it raise error like:

```
requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <requests.packages.urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x03256BB0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 10061]
```

I think it's a problem about permission, but I  don't know how to solve it.
Can you help me ?

Comment: The file to be uploaded must be present locally from where the `upload` is executed.

Comment: yes, I execute 'upload' in windows, and the file to be uploaded is in windows too.

Comment: I tried `client.upload('/', 'd:\a.txt')` and `client.upload('/', 'd:/a.txt')`

Comment: seems you don't have access to your namenode. try accessing http://xx.xx.xx.xx:50070 directly in your browser first

Comment: @Pixou If that is the case, `walk()` should raise error.

Comment: @ franklinsijo Can you give or show me your core-site.xml and dfs-site.xml file?

Answer (score 1):

The namenode will return the address of datanode to client when using `client.upload()`, so you should ensure your client will get to the address. May be you set a hostname for hdfs and not a ip, then you should add a hostname item to your "/etc/hosts" file.